# "vector<bool> iterator not dereferencable" error in MSVC but works perfectly when compiled using g++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, vector, g++

I was writing sieve of eratosthenes algorithm in MSVC using a vector of bools(since I intended on making the array/vector dynamic with user input)

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<vector>

void sieve(std::vector<bool>& prime)
{
    long long size = prime.size();
    long long sq = (long long)sqrt(size);
    if (size >= 2)
        prime[0] = prime[1] = false;
    for (long long i = 2; i <= sq; ++i)
        if (prime[i])
            for (long long j = i*i; j <= size; j += i)
                prime[j] = false;
}

int main()
{
    int m, n;
    std::cout << "Enter first number: ";
    std::cin >> m;
    std::cout << "Enter second number: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<bool> prime(n, true);
    sieve(prime);
    for (long long i = m; i <= n; ++i)
        if (prime[i])
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

I stumbled upon a run time error in MSVC

[MSVC Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbhkF.png)

But this code works perfectly when compiled using g++. I don't know whats wrong. Any help would be appreciable

Thank you

Comment: Did you try it compiling with the -g option and run it with gdb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for (long long i = m; i <= n; ++i)` and `for (long long j = i*i; j <= size; j += i)` will both run past the end of the vector as `vector_name[vector_size]` is 1 past the end of the elements in the vector.  This is undefined behavior and you were unlucky that it worked on g++. Some people never bother to try and compile on another compiler to see if they get the same results and If you hadn't there would have been a silent bug in your "working code".

Change the loops to `for (long long i = m; i < n; ++i)` and `for (long long j = i*i; j < size; j += i)` and you will no longer run past the end of the vector.

Comment: Oh, wow! Subtle but yes, that fixed it.
But I noticed that it works with g++. Any idea why?

Comment: It didn't really "work".  When you overrun array bounds, the behavior is undefined.  Change compiler settings, add code, etc. and watch that "working" program suddenly fail.

Comment: @SagarBHathwar C++ does not fail reliably when you screw up.  When you screw up, you get random stuff, which can be things that seem to work. Which means you have to be disciplined about how you write code, and not just write code that seems to work.  In exchange, you don't get the run-time performance hits that being predicable in failure costs.  In other languages, it attempts to be predictable in failure, but that fails once you pass relatively simple constructs.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (long long j = i*i
  prime[j] = false;
```

This is your problem the position is greater than your size of your vector.

Another thing that I have noticed is the size of your vector should be `n*n`:

```
std::vector<bool> prime(n*n, true);
void sieve(std::vector<bool>& prime,int m,int n)
{
  long long size = prime.size();
  // long long sq = (long long)sqrt(size); you can use n for this so you don't have to make another variable.
  if (size >= 2)
    prime[0] = prime[1] = false;

  for (long long i = m; i < n; ++i)
  {
    if (prime[i])
    {
      for (long long j = i*i; j < n*n; j += i)
      {
        prime[j] = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
int main()
{
  int m, n;
  std::cout << "Enter first number: ";
  std::cin >> m;
  std::cout << "Enter second number: ";
  std::cin >> n;
  std::vector<bool> prime(n*n, true);
  sieve(prime,m,n);
  for (long long i = m; i <= n; ++i)
  {
    if (prime[i])
    {
      std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

this should work ;), and don`t forget to include the headers.